# Eclipse Virgo increasing start/stop time-out [vagrant]

Tags: tomcat, vagrant, eclipse-virgo

Am trying to configure an Eclipse Virgo (Tomcat Apache) instance via Vagrant.

All went well but when I'm trying to start the server up now. It always return this message `<KE0004E> Kernel failed to start within 180 seconds.`. Now I'm stuck and don't know what to do since I'm used to configuring these variable using Eclipse.

The same response was returned when invoking the startup.bat/.sh on the host terminal.

Comment: Have you tried to increase log level ?

Comment: Did you try to configure the timeout as noted in the Virgo User Guide[1] - The parameter is named "org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.startup.wait.limit" and can be configured in "$SERVER_HOME/configuration/config.ini" as noted in [2] ? [1] https://www.eclipse.org/virgo/documentation/virgo-documentation-3.6.4.RELEASE/docs/virgo-user-guide/htmlsingle/virgo-user-guide.html#configuring-kernel [2] https://www.eclipse.org/virgo/documentation/virgo-documentation-3.6.4.RELEASE/docs/virgo-user-guide/htmlsingle/virgo-user-guide.html#configuring-framework-properties

Answer (score 1):

- give more RAM to the VM - if you use VirtualBox, something like

  ```
  VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

  Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
    .....
    config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
      # Customize the amount of memory on the VM:
      vb.memory = "2048"
    end
    ....
  end
  ```
- give more heap to eclipse when it starts

You can change Virgo's JVM memory by editing the files `bin/dmk.sh` (mac/linux) or `bin/dmk.bat` (windows)by changing the `java_opts` parameter:

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m"
```

- extends the wait timeout parameter (https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=366423) in config.ini

  ```
  org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.startup.wait.limit=360
  ```

You can play with all of those options and try them individually.

Comment: Does Eclipse Virgo have a minimum memory requirement? I was hoping to lessen the guest memory. Well as a remedy, increasing the start time-out would do the memory offset?

Comment: I think 521m is a minimum although I did not find clearly on their website - I don't think you should go lower than this. you can increase the start time-out, at least will help you pass the issue but after to have a good user experience you might have to go with increase memory